# How to validate the price in jquery and php?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Can any body help how to validate the price field in jquery and php
the sample currency is

```
 120
120.25
12,23,000
1,000.89
```

I am using this expression but it does not accept comma(,)

it is in jquery

```
value.match(/^[+]?\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/);

and in php i am using 
return (bool) preg_match('/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/', $str);
```

Comment: which of those 4 are valid?

Comment: There are plenty of questions about regex matching currency on SO. Have you searched around? Type `currency [regex]` to the search box.

Comment: Both regexes will validate differently...One allows `+` one doesn't, one allows 2 digits after decimal other 3 digits. It's not consistent. You should first make them do the same thing before you try adding in comma checking.

Answer (score 1):

filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) for integer and filter_var($float, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) for float point
Filter var  sanitizes and validates your input (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) .